# PHPMailer SMTP port 25 connection problem (10060) but same connection via Outlook successful

Tags: smtp, connection, phpmailer

Hello to the community.

I have come across a strange problem with PHPMailer.

I am trying to connect via SMTP to a host without encryption (port 25) and although I am able to connect to the said host via Outlook, the PHPMailer connection attempt fails with the message (10060):

```
Connection: opening to webmail.ypa.gr:25, timeout=300, options=array()<br>
2020-07-21 05:34:34 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to webmail.ypa.gr:25 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) [...]<br>
2020-07-21 05:34:34 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)<br>
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting<br>
```

The parameters (host/port given by the server admins) set to PHPMailer (`$EMAIL_CREDENTIALS`) are dumped below.

```
array(9) {
  ["SMTP_HOST"]=>
  string(14) "webmail.ypa.gr"
  ["SMTP_PORT"]=>
  int(25)
  ["SMTP_AUTH"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["SMTP_SECURE"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SMTP_AUTOTLS"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["USERNAME"]=>
  string(12) "..."
  ["PWD"]=>
  string(6) "..."
  ["SENDER"]=>
  string(12) "..."
  ["RECEIVER"]=>
  string(12) "..."
}
```

This is the code snippet:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

var_dump($EMAIL_CREDENTIALS);

try 
{
    $mail->isSMTP();

    $mail->SMTPDebug    = 4;

    $mail->Host     = $EMAIL_CREDENTIALS["SMTP_HOST"];
    $mail->Port     = $EMAIL_CREDENTIALS["SMTP_PORT"];

    $mail->SMTPAuth     = $EMAIL_CREDENTIALS["SMTP_AUTH"];
    $mail->SMTPSecure   = $EMAIL_CREDENTIALS["SMTP_SECURE"];
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS  = $EMAIL_CREDENTIALS["SMTP_AUTOTLS"];

    $mail->Username     = $EMAIL_CREDENTIALS["USERNAME"];
    $mail->Password     = $EMAIL_CREDENTIALS["PWD"];

    $mail->setFrom($EMAIL_CREDENTIALS["SENDER"], "...");

    $mail->addAddress($to);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($body);

    $mail->send();
}
```

I have seen many answers to such problems but have not been able to fix it. Among others, I have explicitly disabled TLS.
Is there something else I can check?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you connecting **from** the same machine for both outlook and PHPMailer?

Comment: Yes, but the problem persists.

Comment: So you’re running PHP on Windows? Do you have any security software, anti-virus, etc? If so, try turning it off temporarily to see if it’s responsible.

Comment: Yes, it is PHP for windows (7.2.11) and PHPMailer 6.0.5. I have already managed to send emails via PHPMailer SMTP to a Gmail, but the specific webmail refuses to connect (Outlook connection worked though).

Comment: If those work it's not a network problem - but are you sure that you have the right host name? I can't connect to `webmail.ypa.gr` from the outside. It's relatively unusual these days to use port 25 for SMTP submission; use either `ssl` mode with port 465 or `tls` mode with port 587. Is there any reason you're using old versions of both PHP and PHPMailer?

Comment: I'll contact the admins because it's strange indeed.
I'll upgrade to the latest versions although I believe that's not the problem.
I'll comment when I have an answer. Thank you for your help.